# How to Enable Accept.js for Authorize.net in My 3dcart store?

Tags: api, payment-gateway, authorize.net, accept.js

I have to Configure accept.js in Authorize.net Payment Gateway in my 3dcart  store. I have Login Id, Transaction Key, And Public key as well. Do I need To just check- uncheck for enabling this accept.js? Or I need to add the code or this script to the checkout page and call javascript file?  They give me Learn more link (http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html). And How to test it when it's configured well?

Same way I have just added Login Id and Transaction key & checked the check box of Enable Customer Information Manager (CIM) and Its working fine. As I tested it. 
see screenshot: (https://www.screencast.com/t/etPeqTiBJf)

Comment: When you select use Accept.js, are you able to process transactions?

Comment: yes its working by select to use Accept.js.